# Mui Database, Reactjs when i return previous website, pagination reset first page

Tags: reactjs, pagination, mui-datatable

I've using MuidataTable from "mui-datatables", the problem had come when i tried to turn some pages, click to other section and return previous website but the pagination(UI) reset to page 0, and others still right on, here are my code options passing to props MUIDataTable:

```
 const options = {
    filterType: "dropdown",
    responsive: "vertical",
    serverSide: true,
    count: state.count,
    rowsPerPage: state.rowsPerPage,
    rowsPerPageOptions: [],
    sortOrder: state.sortOrder,
    filter: false,
    print: false,
    search: false,
    // resizableColumns: true,
    selectableRows: "none",
    storageKey: "tableState",
    tableState: tableState,
    onTableInit: (action, tableState) =>
      setTableState(localStorage.getItem("tableState")),
    onTableChange: (action, tableState) => {
      // console.log("action", action, tableState);
      switch (action) {
        case "changePage":
          changePage(tableState.page, tableState.sortOrder);
          break;
        case "sort":
          sort(tableState.page, tableState.sortOrder);
          break;
        case "search":
          search(tableState.page, tableState.sortOrder, tableState.searchText);
          break;
        case "propsUpdate":
          // console.log("resetState", resetState);
          if (resetState) {
            tableState.page = 0;
            setResetState(false);
          }
          break;
        default:
          console.log("action not handled.");
          break;
      }
    },

    onRowClick: (rowData, rowState) => {
      console.log(rowData, rowState);
    },
    onDownload: (buildHead, buildBody, columns, data) => {
      if (config.csvDownloadAPI) {
        for (let i = 0, n = config.csvDownloadAPI.length; i < n; i++) {
          let url = config.csvDownloadAPI[i].url;
          const searchText = buildSearchParameter(searchState);
          url = _.isEmpty(searchText) ? url : `${url}?${searchText}`;
          api({
            url: url, //your url
            method: "GET",
            responseType: "blob", // important
          }).then((response) => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute(
              "download",
              `${config.csvDownloadAPI[i].fileName}_${new Date()}.${
                config.csvDownloadAPI[i].extension
              }`,
            ); //or any other extension
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
          });
        }
        return false;
      }
    },
    
    customToolbar: () => (
      showAddToolbar && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Tooltip title={"Create New"}>
            <IconButton onClick={createNew}>{<AddCardIcon />}</IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    ),
  };
```

Please help me fix the UI pagination when the back previous website